# Search for age in php

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to build up a search function, which gets the results by an age range. The database containts the birthday of an user (e.g. 1980-09-11 00:00:00). Now I am trying to search for users e.g. by using $agefrom = 15; and $ageto = 18;.. But I do not now how the php code and the db statement should look like..

I want to make the most stuff in php and then only do a sql query like (birth < birth_to AND birth > birth_from)..

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest query, which won't work with total accuracy would be

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE YEAR(birthday) BETWEEN (YEAR(now()) - 18, YEAR(now()) - 15)
```

This will fail if a person's birthday has not yet occured in a particular year (e.g. it's May 1st, and their b-day is June 15th). Handling that case will require a bit more date math to check for "year is right but day/month is wrong".

Answer (score 0):

I would think it's easiest to construct the dates you need as 15 and 18 years ago (in PHP), then place those in the query with a BETWEEN statement.  Round to midnight or you'll get bad edge cases.

Comment: But the problem is there, that i get no exact results, if a person has not yet birthday in the year.. How to solve that?

Comment: @simons Add one year to `$ageto`.